# Stretching after workout

Tags: stretching

I had a great weight loss (46lbs!) mainly focusing on a life style change. I have recently started a fight fit class which involves kicking and punching a bag and some cardio for 45 minutes.  A great workout! heres my question: I live 5 minutes away from the gym, is it ok to drive home and do my stretching then... say 10ish minutes after this workout. its not really a gym its a dojo and I have a video I like to do for my stretching at home but are my muscles cooled by then?
Thank you for your time!
Misty

Answer (score 2):

First, congrats on the weight loss, great job, Misty!

I would perform your stretch routine within 30 minutes, but I'm not sure I would push it much more than that if you want to have an effective stretching session.

If you wait too long, it'll be like trying to stretch a frozen rope and you won't be as effective at removing lactic acid.  Once the muscles and tendons cool down, the chances of tearing of either or other unwanted trauma increases.

Comment: Hey thanks for the response! My stretch will be within 10 minutes of my workout so it sounds like I will be ok doing that! Im baby stepping kettlebell workouts into my routine but at home so theres no problem stretching directly after there. Just those two days doing the fight fit class down the street. Again thank you!